# How to get distinct nodes in a path in NEO4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to cypher and Neo4j I have trouble collecting all the distinct nodes in the path of Neo4j.

```
MATCH (e)
WHERE SIZE((e:Customer)<-[:Transaction]-()) <> 0
AND SIZE(()<-[:Transaction]-(e)) <> 0
MATCH path = (e)<-[:Transaction*10..15]-(e)
with e,nodes(path) as nods return (how to return distinct of nods)
```

After getting the nodes from path how to get the distinct nodes in that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH (e)
WHERE SIZE((e:Customer)<-[:Transaction]-()) <> 0
AND SIZE(()<-[:Transaction]-(e)) <> 0
MATCH path = (e)<-[:Transaction*10..15]-(e)
with e,nodes(path) as nods
UNWIND nods as node
RETURN e, COLLECT(DISTINCT node)
```

this query will do.
but , you do not have to do

```
WHERE SIZE((e:Customer)<-[:Transaction]-()) <> 0
AND SIZE(()<-[:Transaction]-(e)) <> 0
```

instead

```
WHERE e:Customer AND (e)-[:Transaction]->() AND (e)<-[:Transaction]-()
```

will be better performance wise